# Is it possible to make ownership of /proc/pid/io follow changed process ownership?

Tags: python-2.7

One of my python scripts has to be started as root but after some initialization changes its process ownership to something else by calling setuid/setgid.  Works like a champ except for one thing:  most of the files under /prod/pid are still owned by root and most important /proc/pid/io is owned by root so I can't monitor that process's I/O stats.  Might there be some additional calls I can make to change /proc ownership?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a Python question - seems to be more involving the linux kernel...

Answer (score 0):

That is by design.

The process may still hold a capability (i.e. a handle to something external to the process) that would not be available to the process owner otherwise, so most debugging facilities are available to the root user only.